# A question related to stars and bars method

Tags: combinatorics

I was reading [this question](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-number-of-ways-to-distribute-8-identical-balls-in-3-different-boxes-none-being-empty) on quora, **number of ways to distribute 8 identical balls in 3 different boxes, none being empty**,  [Kavita Chawdhary](https://www.quora.com/profile/Kavita-Chawdhary) gave an excellent answer but I was thinking if I remove the condition **none being empty** then what the answer would be.

★ ★ ★ ★ ★ ★ | ★ | ★

There will be $8$ stars and the $2$ bars can go to any of the $9$ places because there is no restriction now. But it gives $\binom{9}{2}$. But it is not of course what stars bars algorithm says, $\binom{n + k - 1}{n}$. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: There will be 8 stars and the 2 bars, so you have ten places and you get  $\binom{10}{2}$ possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have reduced the problem to counting strings of $n=8$ stars and $k-1=2$ bars. There are actually 10 places that the bars can go, not 9, so $\binom{10}{2}$ options. This is equal to the $\binom{n+k-1}{n}=\binom{10}{8}$ by symmmetry of Pascal's triangle.

Comment: I just wonder where is the $10th$ option

Comment: I'm not sure which option you're not seeing, but perhaps you're forgetting that bars could go at both the front or back of the string?

Comment: $_1 ★_2 ★_3 ★_4 ★_5 ★_6 ★_7 ★_8 ★_9$

Comment: Ah! The other spot you are missing is *behind the other bar*. In fact, don't think of inserting bars into a string of stars. Just think of choosing which two characters in your final ten-character string will be bars.

Comment: so it is it $_1 ★_2 ★_3 ★_4 ★_5 ★_6  ★_7 ★_8 \mid_9 ★_{10}$. Thanks

Comment: That's better. Obviously the first bar doesn't need to be in that particular position though :)